# Weird statement loop

Tags: c, function, if-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


//prototype
void input(int *);
void statements(int, int);
void print(int, int *);




void main()
{
   int num, guess;
   time_t t;

   srand((unsigned) time(&t));
   num=rand()% 100+1;

   printf("%d\n", num);

   input(&guess);
   statements(num, guess);

}



void input(int *guess)
{
   printf("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
   scanf("%d", &*guess);
}

void statements (int num, int guess)
{


   if(guess==num)
      printf("You have guessed correct! The number is: %d", num);
   else if(guess>num)
   {
      printf("The number you have guessed is too big\n");
      print(num, &guess);

   }
   else if(guess<num)
   {
      printf("The number you have guessed is too small\n");
      print(num, &guess);
   }

}




    void print( int num, int *guess)
    {

        printf("Guess again: ");
        scanf("%d", &*guess);
        statements(num, guess);
    }
```

Basically, I am writing a program for a guessing game as an assignment and the user keeps getting tries until his/her answer is correct; however, when I execute it, if the user doesn't get it correct the first time, the program keeps telling him the number is too big no matter what. No loops allowed
Example:
85
Guess a number between 1 and 100: 90
The number you have guessed is too big
Guess again: 20
The number you have guessed is too big
Guess again:

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger? Do that, while monitoring variables and their values, and you should hopefully be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: A good hint though, should be the warnings your compiler will give you for the code. You're not passing the correct argument types to all function calls.

Comment: On an unrelated note, when you call `scanf` to read the guess, the variable `guess` already is a pointer. The address-of `&` and dereference `*` operators cancels each-other out. `&*guess` is equal to plain `guess`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger", what if he uses GCC on MinGW?

Comment: when you call `statements(num, guess);` inside `print` you are passing a pointer and casting it into an int.  As @Someprogrammerdude points out, your compiler would give a warning about a type mismatch.

Comment: @FREE_AND_OPEN_SOURCE So then the OP could use GDB? If the OP uses an IDE then it will probably come with GDB and a frontend for it.

Comment: Just to point out, main() must have a return type "int".

Answer (score 0):

Other than the problems pointed out by the comments, your use of recursion is a potential problem.  If the user keeps guessing wrong, you'll eventually blow out the call stack.  Also, the sequence of pointer reference, dereference, i.e. `&*` doesn't do anything, so you should take it out.  So, the correct code with a while loop instead of using recursion would be something like this:

```
void statements (int num, int guess)
{
    while (guess!=num) { 
        if(guess>num) {
            printf("The number you have guessed is too big\n");
            print(num, &guess);
        } else if(guess<num) {
            printf("The number you have guessed is too small\n");
            print(num, &guess);
        }
    }
    printf("You have guessed correct! The number is: %d\n", num);
}

void print( int num, int *guess)
{
    printf("Guess again: ");
    scanf("%d", guess);
}
```